# What is the difference between "element" and "//element" in XPath?

Tags: xpath

I am reading this XPath examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx and I want to know the difference between these 2 expressions:

```
author
All <author> elements within the current context.

//author
All <author> elements in the document.
```

What is the difference between these two cases? If the "current context" is the root node, would that make the two equivalent?

For this simple XML file:

```
<root>
    <author>
        <first-name></first-name>
    </author>
</root>
```

I tried it on this site https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Why does `author` not returning anything as I expected it should (but `//author` works)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [description you cite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) for the relative XPath expression, `author`,

> All `<author>` elements within the current context.

is **wrong**<sup>1</sup>.  It should instead say,

> All `<author>` ***child*** elements of the current context ***node***.

`//author` would indeed select all `<author>` elements in the document because `//` selects along the `descendant-or-self` axis.

The reason `author` doesn't select anything for your XML document is that with the context node set to the document root, you'd have to include `root/author` to select the `<author>` children of `<root>` or just `root` to select the `<root>` element itself.

<sub><sup>1</sup>  As of today, 2018-06-24, but I've submitted feedback that it should be corrected, so hopefully it will fixed be soon.</sub>

Comment: Isn't the root node (in my example `<root>`) also the document node? So when we evaluate the XML isn't it also the context node? In which case `<author>` is one of its children so the `author` expression should be able to return the `<author>` node shouldn't it? What did I understand wrong?

Comment: @Chin: No, your `root` element is the ***document element***.  On the other hand, the [***root node***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#root-node) *is the root of the tree. A root node does not occur except as the root of the tree. The element node for the document element is a child of the root node. The root node also has as children processing instruction and comment nodes for processing instructions and comments that occur in the prolog and after the end of the document element.*

Answer (score 2):

"`element`" selects all immediate children named "element" of the current node and is identical to "`./element`".

"`//element`" selects all "element" nodes at any depth, starting from the root (ignoring your current node).

And to complete the list:

"`.//element`" would select "element" children below the current node, at any depth.

"`/element`" would search at the root level only (in you example, you would need "/root" to get anything).

And as for "`author`" not finding anything: you first need to be at the level of your root node. "`/root/author`" would get the node you wanted, or first select "`/root`" and from there you can select "`author`".

Comment: I thought when I evaluate an XML document, if I don't specify the starting node, it will start at the root node? If it doesn't start at the root node then where?

Comment: @Chin: No, without a leading `/`, an XPath expression is ***relative*** to the current context node.  The fact that the [**reference you cite is unfortunately *wrong***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51010875/290085) likely contributed to your misunderstanding.